# Using params as wildcards in Snakemake rule outputs

Tags: snakemake

In Snakefile, is it possible to define a param using wildcards and then use it as
a variable in the output specification?

Consider the following example:

```py
rule train_stuff:
  input:
    "input.{lang}.txt"
  params:
    prefix="model.{lang}"
  output:
    "{params.prefix}.npz",
    "{params.prefix}.vocab",
    "{params.prefix}.some_other_auxiliary_output"
  shell:
    """
    # ... stuff that creates the three output files ... 
    touch {output[0]}
    touch {output[1]}
    touch {output[2]}
    """
```

I can do it by replacing each `{params.prefix}` in the output with the actual prefix, but I was wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this. The code above gives the following error:

```
WildcardError in rule train_stuff in file (...)/Snakefile, line 2:
Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
'lang'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently that's not possible. There's an open feature request [on GitHub](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1122) which also provides a few workarounds.

Since you are reading the value for your `params` from somewhere, maybe it is an option to refer to the same datasource in `output` which you also use in `params`?